# Составное условие в валидаторе

Tags: python, django

помогите пожалуйста исправить валидацию

есть форма с полями: фамилия, имя, отчество, логин, ник, что показывать. вешаю валидацию на поле "что показывать". что показывать это выпадающий список типа select.

работать должно следующим образом. например пользователь выбирает из выпадающего списка "фамилия" и если при этом поле "фамилия заполнено", то форма отправляется. если не заполнено - выводится сообщение об ошибке

models.py:
    class UserProfile(User):
        CHOICES_name_label = (
            ('0', 'nick', ),
            ('1', 'login',),
            ('2', 'family', ),
            ('3', 'family name1 name2', ),
        )

```
    family = models.CharField(
        'Фамилия',
        max_length=30, 
        blank=True,
    )
    name1 = models.CharField(
        'Имя',
        max_length=30, 
        blank=True,
    )
    name2 = models.CharField(
        'Отчество',
        max_length=30, 
        blank=True,
    )
    nickname = models.CharField(
        'Ник',
        max_length=30, 
        blank=True,
    )
    name_label = models.CharField(
        'Показывать на странице имя как',
        max_length=30, 
        choices=CHOICES_name_label,         
        blank=False,
        default=1,
    )
```

forms.py:

```
class PersonalDataForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_name_label(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        name_label = cleaned_data.get("name_label").strip()
        nickname = cleaned_data.get("nickname").strip()
        family = cleaned_data.get("family").strip()
        name1 = cleaned_data.get("name1").strip()
        name2 = cleaned_data.get("name2").strip()

        if name_label == '0' and not nickname:
            raise forms.ValidationError("0")

        if name_label == '2' and not family:
            raise forms.ValidationError("2")

        if name_label == '3' and not family and not name1 and not name2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("3")

        return name_label
```

проблема в том, что срабатывают условия валидации:

```
    if name_label == '0' and not nickname:
        raise forms.ValidationError("0")

    if name_label == '2' and not family:
        raise forms.ValidationError("2")
```

и не срабатывает условие валидации:

```
    if name_label == '3' and not family and not name1 and not name2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если валидация обрабатывает несколько полей, ее нельзя делать в методе `clean_FIELD`, потому что `dict` с полями обходится в случайном порядке, и никто не гарантирует, что к моменту валидации поля A в `cleaned_data` будет лежать результат валидации поля B.

Используйте метод `clean`, он работает [после валидации всех полей по отдельности.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)